# DataContext: Same Tables Structure but different table names for different department

Tags: c#, sql, datacontext

This post is similar to this article but yet different.
My question this is:
Within a databse, I have two different sets of tables with identical structure, but different names.
For example:

**Table set 1:** MasterA -childA1 -childA2  -childA3

**Table Set 2:** MasterB -childB1  -childB2 -childB3

A and B are each used by different department in my company.
I'm trying to use **C# DataContext** as it is quite easy to use (though not as good as Delphi in old time). But DataContext needs to be hard wired to each table before coding.
In older days where we can write

```
string SQLStr = "....from Master" + departmentID + " where ...."
```

I'm trying to reuse my code as much as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Is this Linq2SQL or Entity framework?

Comment: Linq to SQL.  Example link (in case I'm wrong) : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx

Comment: Is it ok to load the 2 sets of tables into the same dbml? will it be weird?